# Why blender is not registering its website on brave rewards?

Tags: development

I was trying to send blender some fund but my brave browser said that blender website is not registered for brave rewards.

Comment: Wrong community.

Answer (score 1):

Blender has its own platform for donations. You can donate to [Blender development fund](https://fund.blender.org/) or make a [one time donation](https://www.blender.org/foundation/donation-payment/) using the listed options that include PayPal and even several cryptocurrencies.